# Invalid conversion of int to unsigned int

Tags: c++, montecarlo, pi

This code is given for the assignment. However, off the bat there is an error in the compute pi monte carlo function. the error stats invalid of conversion from int to unsigned int. Im not sure if this was intended, but i haven't been able to correct this issue. This function is part of threading example in case you were wondering. Any suggestions is most appreciated

```
void *compute_pi( void *s )   
{
int seed;
int ii;
int *hit_pointer;
int local_hits;
double rand_no_x;
double rand_no_y;

hit_pointer = (int *) s;
seed = *hit_pointer;
local_hits = 0;

for( ii=0; ii < sample_points_per_thread; ii++ )
{
  rand_no_x = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;//*error is these lines
  rand_no_y = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;//*error is these lines
  if(((rand_no_x - 0.5) * (rand_no_x - 0.5) +
  (rand_no_y - 0.5) * (rand_no_y - 0.5)) < 0.25)//*error 
local_hits++;
  seed *= ii;
 }

*hit_pointer = local_hits;
 pthread_exit(0); 
 }
```

i did some debugging and now see where the error may be located. ill post now the main function where compute pi is called. I believe it is where arguments are parsed into sample points and number of threads. When i run the program it asks for input afterwards it fails with segementation fault. Any suggestions?

```
  #include <pthread.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define MAX_THREADS 512

  void *compute_pi( void * );


  int sample_points;
  int total_hits;
  int total_misses;
  int hits[ MAX_THREADS ];
  int sample_points_per_thread;
  int num_threads;



  int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
  {
  /* local variables */
  int ii;
  int retval;
  pthread_t p_threads[MAX_THREADS];
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  double computed_pi;

  /* initialize local variables */
  retval = 0;


  pthread_attr_init( &attr );
  pthread_attr_setscope( &attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM );

  printf( "Enter number of sample points: " );
  scanf( "%d", &sample_points );
  printf( "Enter number of threads: " );
  scanf( "%d%", &num_threads );

  /* parse command line arguments into sample points and number of threads */
  /* there is no error checking here!!!!! */
  sample_points = atoi(argv[1]);
  num_threads = atoi(argv[2]);


  total_hits = 0;
  sample_points_per_thread = sample_points / num_threads;

  for( ii=0; ii<num_threads; ii++ )
  {
  hits[ii] = ii;
  pthread_create( &p_threads[ ii ], &attr, compute_pi, (void *) &hits[ii] );
  }

  for( ii=0; ii<num_threads; ii++ )
  {
   pthread_join( p_threads[ ii ], NULL );
   total_hits += hits[ ii ];
    }

   computed_pi = 4.0 * (double) total_hits / ((double) (sample_points));


   printf( "Computed PI = %lf\n", computed_pi );


   /* return to calling environment */
   return( retval );
   }
```

Comment: Intended or not, the original "fix" appears to stem from declaring `seed` to match the cast-type of the provided `void*` parameter `hit_pointer`. This "matchup" is carried over. You are correct that [`rand_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r) does indeed spec to use an `unsigned int*` as its single parameter.

Comment: Read error messages carefully and don't paraphrase them. The error is **not** invalid conversion of `int` to `unsigned`; that's okay. The error is invalid conversion of `int*` to `unsigned*`, which is considerably different.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`rand_r(3)` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/rand_r/osx-10.4.php):

```
int
rand_r(unsigned *ctx);
```

As you can see, it takes an `unsigned` pointer - if you pass it an `int` and you have the appropriate warnings/errors turned on in your compiler (and it seems you do), you'll get that error.  Change the type of `seed` and you'll be set.

Comment: And change the type of `hit_pointer` as well. Oh, and `local_hits`.

Comment: but they are supposed to be int datatypes right? since they are dealing with integers. hit_pointer is assigned an int by the number that is entered for sample points and for seed.

Comment: ok i did this "unsigned int seed;" and no error came up only now with an undefined reference to pthread_create and pthread_join. im guessing there is an error to what is being passed to create and join threads in main?

Comment: No, that means you're not linking your threads library.  Try adding `-lpthread` to your link step.

Comment: Yes, maybe.  You might need `-lpthread` at the end rather than in the middle, though.  Did you try it?

Comment: hmm it creates an .out file and when i run it, segmentation fault

Comment: ... time to start debugging

Comment: Your code is reading the arguments from `stdin`, but then you try to parse command line arguments using `argv`.  Which is it?  Don't do both.